# calling ssis package from stored procedure without using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

My application actually calls a stored procedure which inturn calls a package and execute it.Initially we are doing it using xp_cmdshell and dtexec but client disallows to use xm_cmdshell.Is there is any other way to do this?

Please help.

Comment: SQL 2012 delivers procedures to run packages natively  [catalog.create_execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878160(v=sql.110).aspx) and [catalog.start_execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878160(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: The problem is that application and package reesides on the same server ie application server.According to client we are not permitted to install integration services on the application server.Our db server is different.Our application executes package on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is [discussed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx) in the SSIS documentation. Another option would be a CLR procedure that [runs the package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx), so instead of TSQL/xp_cmdshell you use CLR/Dts object model.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a job that runs the package and then use `sp_start_job` to execut the job

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx

You can use these commands to create the job programatically

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153.aspx

Comment: but it will create problem in case of concurrent users.suppose one user clicks a button which will invoke this sp_startjob.But if at the same time other user clicks this button then he/she will not be able to execute it until first one finishes it.

Comment: Perhaps instead of running an existing job, run a script that creates the job, then you could add a unique GUID to the job and track it's progress as well  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191450.aspx